# What is the solution path yielded by a DFS on this graph

Tags: search, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search

[image: Graph]

Using a DFS on this graph, the nodes are visited in the following order(for more than one successor node, nodes are pushed to the "frontier" in alphabetical order):

S->A->E->D->F->G

Is that visitation sequence the solution path aswell? If so, why is it not S->A->E->G, since G is also a successor node of E?

PS: Im new to algorithms, so if I'm clearly not understanding the concept, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are visiting the nodes, the DFS approach will traverse the graph based on the creation order of the adjacency list.

For example, the order of inserting node `E`'s successors may be in the following ways:

```
1- E-> D, G
2- E-> G, D
```

In the first way, you will traverse `D->F->G` or `D->G` directly and in both cases you will visit node `G` before traversing any of node `E` other successors, so you will not be able to traverse the path`S->A->E->G` because node `G` will be already visited before from node `D` or `F`.

In the second way, you will traverse `E->G` directly, so this will result in traversing the path `S->A->E->G`, but also you will not be able to access node `G` from node `D` or `F` because it will be already visited from node `E`.

The previous scenario will happen if you are visiting with true or false, but if you are trying to find the shortest path using the costs on edges, then you will need to use `Dijkstra`'s algorithm for finding shortest path on a graph, and you can read more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) if you are not familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume its taking into account both the heuristic and edge cost to determine the next node to visit.

Starting at S it looks at its three possibilities:

```
A = 9 + 13 = 21
B = 14 + 14 = 28
C = 15 + 15 = 30
```

It then chooses A and looks at its only available path from A and goes to E.

From E we have two possibilities:

```
D = 2 + 8 = 10
G = 19 + 0 = 19
```

It will then choose D and now it has two possibilities:

```
F = 11 + 5 = 16
G = 16 + 0 = 16
```

Its a tie so depending on how the algorithm was set it up and the solution you gave it goes to F which then has two possibilities:

```
E = 6 + 7 = 13
G = 6 + 0 = 6
```

It then goes to G and finally it sees that this is the goal node and returns the state sequence.